# Term for non-record data constructors in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```hs
data A b c = B | C b | H { b :: b, c :: c }
```

AFAIK, `B` is called nullary constructor `C` is called unary constructor, while `H` is called record.

But what is the term for arbitrary-arity constructors including both `B` and `C`?
Is there something better than non-record constructors?

Comment: I can't think of any better term. Note that mixing record and non-record constructors in the same type is generally considered something to avoid, since it makes the fields partial functions.

Comment: I suppose the are called sum types.

Comment: @Redu That's only if you consider `B` as representing an anonymous type isomorphic to `()` and `C` representing one isomorphic to `b`. Also, `H` would also be included in the sum (representing something isomorphic to `(b, c)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure they *deserve* a special name.  A record constructor is basically just a non-record constructor with some automatically defined accessor functions and convenient syntactic support.  In your example above, I would consider `H` a binary constructor or a constructor of arity 2, since I can construct and destruct it like any other binary constructor:

```
let H a b = H (1+1) (2+2) in (a,b)
```

For what it's worth, the Haskell98 report just calls them "constructors with field labels" and "constructors without field labels" and makes it pretty clear that even with field labels they are still "data constructors of arity k".